# Set File Paths - Perl Script

Tags: perl

What I am trying to do is take the bcp log file out (log folder) and move it to another directory with a current time (history folder). However, every time I execute this Perl script, it states "No such file or directory at line 18"

Below is my code:

```
## SET FILE PATHS
my $myBCPDump = "//Server-A/X:/Main Folder/Log/bcpLog.txt";
my $myBCPLog = "//Server-A/X:/Main Folder/History/bcpLog" . $myDate . ".txt"; 

my $isJunk = "rows successfully|rows sent to SQL|packet size|Starting copy|^\n|Clock Time";

open (LOGFILE, ">$myBCPLog") or die $!; ##Line 18

close (LOGFILE);
```

I know that it can't find the file or directory is because the ##SET FILE PATHS is not being executed properly and I am not sure why.

Comment: What OS are you using? `//Server-A/X:/...` is not a valid path in Windows, and I've never seen anything like that in unix before.

Comment: what do you mean it is not a valid path?

Comment: `:` isn't allowed except after a drive letter (`C:...`). But you have a UNC path (`\\server\share\...`), and those don't have a drive component. Did you perhaps mean `//Server-A/X$/...`? Don't forget to escape the `$`

Comment: I have already tried that, it still gave me the same error.

Comment: I can't see your network, so I can't tell you why else the path doesn't exist. Neither can anyone else.

Comment: Does it matter if I use / or \? Becuase when I use \, I get an error stating Use of uninitialized value $\ in concatentation <.> or string

Comment: Windows APIs accept / & \ interchangeably, but be aware that string literals in Perl may use \ as an escape character in various circumstances, particularly at the start of a UNC path.

Comment: @ikegami you were right with the escape $. I thought it was suppose to be X\$/Main Folder, but then I realized it was suppose to be like this X\$\/Main Folder. If you add that as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: What you just said makes no sense. `"X\$/Main Folder"` and `"X\$\/Main Folder"` produce the same string, `X$/Main Folder`.

Comment: Yet for some reason "X\$/Main Folder" did not work, but "X\$\/Main Folder" did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//Server-A/X:/...` isn't a valid path in Windows. A colon (`:`) isn't allowed in a path except after a drive letter (`C:...`). But you have a UNC path (`\\server\share\...` aka `//server/share/...`), and those don't have a drive component. Did you perhaps mean `//Server-A/X$/...`? If so,

```
"//Server-A/X:/..."
```

should be changed to either of

```
"//Server-A/X\$/..."
```

and

```
'//Server-A/X$/...'
```